# Total price in label from Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is calculation of the total price in C# and I want to show the total price of products in the label [Like in an image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofJia.png)

The row with the `SalesForm.TotalPrice` calculates the total price:

```
if (cbxProdTypeSwitch.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    // phones 
    Smartphone ph = (Smartphone)dgvProds.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;

    SalesForm.productName = ph.ProductName;
    SalesForm.price = ph.price;
    SalesForm.totalPrice = ph.price * Convert.ToInt32(nudAmount.Value);
    SalesForm.salesDate = DateTime.Now;
    SalesForm.amount = Convert.ToInt32(nudAmount.Value);
    SalesForm.clientName = tbxClient.Text;
}
```

Comment: what is `SalesForm`? What is the name of the label `Total`?

Comment: SalesForm is an auto property (get, set)

Comment: label name just label1, I think  the name of the label doesnt matter now

Comment: You can not do `label1.Text = SalesForm.TotalPrice;`?

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'string'.... ToString convertation also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

if wanna show an int or double value as `String`,
then you should do this:

INT

```
label1.Text = SalesForm.totalPrice.ToString();
```

DOUBLE

```
label1.Text = SalesForm.totalPrice.ToString("0.00"); //for currency
label1.Text = SalesForm.totalPrice.ToString("0.##"); //if you want to eliminate the ".00"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want currency, use the named format.

```
label1.Text = $"{SalesForm.totalPrice:C2}";
```